# put a footnote just in down margin no near of body text

Tags: positioning, margins, footnotes

i want put footnote just margin down no near body text 
i find this where i can handle the space between body text and down margin  but is hard calculate space for all my footnotes

```
\footins\setlength{\skip\footins}{2cm}\footnote{cf. F. P. Ramsey. \textit{The foundations of Mathematics}, London Mathematical Society.}
```

someone known method for do it automatically?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528).  The one line of code you provided is not going to do anything useful other than put four words in italics.